# Query JSON String

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-2.0

Is there a way to query a JSON (String) for a specific item?

ie:

```
String jSon = "{\"a\":{\"b\":27472483,\"c\":\"123\"}}";
```

such that:

```
Int32 bob = (Int32)getFromJSON("a.b", jSon);
// bob == 27472483
```

Thank you,
-Theo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public T getFromJSON<T>(String sel, String jSon)
    {
        String[] id = sel.Split('.');
        Object tmp = jSon;

        for (int i = 0; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            tmp = tmp.ToString().Split(new string[] { "\"" + id[i] + "\":" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[1];
        }

        Boolean isString = false;
        if (tmp.ToString().StartsWith("\""))
        {
            tmp = tmp.ToString().Substring(1);
            isString = true;
        }

        tmp = tmp.ToString().Split(new char[] { '}', ']', '"' }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];

        if (!isString && tmp.ToString().EndsWith(","))
            tmp = tmp.ToString().Substring(0, tmp.ToString().Length - 1);

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(Int32))
            tmp = Int32.Parse(tmp.ToString());

        return (T)tmp;
    }
```

v0.7b Works!

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do here is to deserialize the JSON string into a C# object, and then access the 'b' property from there. [More on that here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx)

Comment: This i know how to do, but this means that you have to define each object you want to query before-hand.

Comment: Most commonly because it's based on a JSON returned via a third party API, and as such the definition is constantly changing, as they develop their service.

Comment: @Theofanis Pantelides: alright, then here's an interesting example on different solutions to that (the first one, for c# 2.0, not being a solution): http://blogs.msdn.com/alexghi/archive/2008/12/22/using-anonymous-types-to-deserialize-json-data.aspx